# Psensor usage and CPU load

Tags: cpu-load, psensor

When p sensor is being displayed top shows CPU usage some thing low like 1 or 2 percent.
When I minimize p sensor top shows CPU usage goes wild 50, 60, 80 percent.

### What gives?

Side issue I could not write p sensor in this message due to some error handling issues, please pardon.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar.  Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64, on a Lenovo W510 i7 box w/nvidia graphics.  CPU load jumps and temps rise (fans get louder, too) when the screen blanks/locks, and it doesn't happen if I shut down psensor first.

Comment: I neglected to mention that it makes no difference whether I'm using the nVidia proprietary or nouveau drivers.  Same symptom.

Comment: The background CPU usage of psensor has a strong correlation with the size of the graph area.

Comment: @RobertK.Bell  interesting observation.  The original question states CPU use rises dramatically when psensor is minimized.  In my case, the CPU use rises dramatically when the screen blanks or locks with psensor not minimized.  With the psensor graph visible on the desktop, it drops to a reasonable value.  I'll try making the graph area very small and see if CPU use is reduced when screen blanking/locked.

Comment: @John I can confirm that changing the theme to other than Ambience or Radience is a workaround until the official fix is released for xenial.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug but here is a workaround until there is a bug fix.  Close the psensor graph window instead of minimizing it.  When you want to view the psensor graph window again right click the little psensor thermometer icon in the panel (top bar), click "Show" and then click the psensor icon on the Launcher (left sidebar) to show and put focus on the psensor graph window.

The spike in CPU usage doesn't only occur when the psensor graph window is minimized but anytime the graph window does not have the focus.  You can verify this by having just one other small window on the desktop, Terminal for instance, and Alt-Tab between them.  You'll see the CPU usage jump and fall as you do.

This is a bug with psensor 1.1.3-2ubuntu**3** in ubuntu 16.04. The jump in CPU usage does **not** occur in an identically configured psensor 1.1.3-2ubuntu**2** in ubuntu 15.10.

I'm running a custom built PC with an AMD A8-3870 APU and no discrete graphics card or motherboard graphics.  I am not using proprietary graphics drivers just the default graphics with ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04.

Comment: psensor 1.1.5 fixes this issue but is not available in the default ubuntu repositories yet.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/psensor/+bug/1582930 for more info on the fix and where it is currently available.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the default themes (i.e. use a different one from Ambiance or Radiance) is a workaround until the fix is released for Xenial.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar in Ubuntu 22.04 (~100% CPU when psensor graph is up, even if focused) and the workaround still works.  Thanks!